# How to get rid of goto and flip in the following program

Tags: c++, c

How to get rid of `goto` statement in this program and end the `flip:>>>`?

```
int main()
{
    int array[10];
    int sum = 0;
    int desending;
    int mul = 1;

    float avg = 10;

    int option;

    do
    {
flip1:
        cout << "\n\t\t------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "\t\tlllllllll           Menue            lllllllllll" << endl;
        cout << "\t\tlllllllll 1.    Array Basics         lllllllllll" << endl;
        cout << "\t\tlllllllll 2.    Searching Array      lllllllllll" << endl;
        cout << "\t\tlllllllll 3.    Sorting Array        lllllllllll" << endl;
        cout << "\t\tlllllllll 4.    Exit                 lllllllllll" << endl;
        cout << "\t\t------------------------------------------------\n" << endl;
        cout << "Please select an option" << endl;
        cin >> option;
        system("cls");
flip2:
        if (option == 1)
        {
            int h = 1;
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {

                cout << h << "  Enter the Numbers  ";

                cin >> array[i];

                sum = sum + array[i];

                mul = mul*array[i];

                h++;
            }
            system("cls");

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {

                cout << "Given numbers" << j << " =  " << array[j] << "\n";


            }
            avg = sum / avg;
            int max = array[0];
            int min = array[0];


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (array[i] > max)
                {
                    max = array[i];
                }
                else if (array[i] < min)
                {
                    min = array[i];
                }

            }
            cout << "\nSum of the Numbers= 4" << sum << endl;
            cout << "\nProduct of the Numbers is = " << mul << endl;
            cout << "\nThe Avg of Numbers is     = " << avg << endl;
            cout << "\nmaximum of the Numbers is = " << max << endl;
            cout << "\nminimum of the Numbers is = " << min << endl;
        }
        else if (option == 2)
        {
            int array[10], o, index = -1;
            cout << "enter the elements of array" << endl;
            for (o = 0; o < 10; o++)
            {
                cin >> array[o];

            }
            system("cls");
            int p;
            cout << "enter value to find" << endl;
            cin >> p;
            for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
            {
                if (array[c] == p)

                    index = c;
            }
            system("cls");
            if (index == -1)
            {
                cout << "no value found" << endl;
            }
            else
                cout << "Value found at\t" << index << endl;

        }
        else if (option == 3)
        {
            system("cls");
            int a[10], r, t, temp;
            cout << "Enter the array elements: " << endl;
            for (r = 0; r<10; ++r)
                cin >> a[r];
            system("cls");
            for (r = 0; r<10; ++r)
            for (t = 0; t<9; t++)
            if (a[r]<a[t])
            {
                temp = a[r];
                a[r] = a[t];
                a[t] = temp;
            }

            cout << "Array after sorting: " << endl;
            for (r = 0; r<10; r++)
                cout << a[r] << "\t ";

        }

        cout << "\nplease select an option\n" << endl;
        cout << "press m for main menue" << endl;
        cout << "press r for repeat" << endl;
        cout << "press e for exit" << endl;
        char q;
        cin >> q;
        if (q == 'm')
        {
            system("cls");
            goto flip1;
        }
        if (q == 'r')
        {
            system("cls");
            goto flip2;
        }
        if (q == 'e')
        {
            return 0;
        }
    } while (option != 4);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Split your code into small functions that each do one thing

Comment: lol, Is this a port of a basic program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the below code.

Before entering the loop.

```
cout << "\n\t\t------------------------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "\t\tlllllllll           Menue            lllllllllll" << endl;
cout << "\t\tlllllllll 1.    Array Basics         lllllllllll" << endl;
cout << "\t\tlllllllll 2.    Searching Array      lllllllllll" << endl;
cout << "\t\tlllllllll 3.    Sorting Array        lllllllllll" << endl;
cout << "\t\tlllllllll 4.    Exit                 lllllllllll" << endl;
cout << "\t\t------------------------------------------------\n" << endl;
cout << "Please select an option" << endl;
cin >> option;
system("cls");    

do {
    if (option == 1)
    {
        int h = 1;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            /* All text as same */
```

At the end: change

```
if (q == 'm')
{
    system("cls");
    goto flip1;
}
if (q == 'r')
{
    system("cls");
    goto flip2;
}
if (q == 'e')
{
    return 0;
}
```

To.

```
if (q == 'e')
{
    return 0;
}
system("cls");
if (q == 'm')
{
    cout << "\n\t\t------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\t\tlllllllll           Menue            lllllllllll" << endl;
    cout << "\t\tlllllllll 1.    Array Basics         lllllllllll" << endl;
    cout << "\t\tlllllllll 2.    Searching Array      lllllllllll" << endl;
    cout << "\t\tlllllllll 3.    Sorting Array        lllllllllll" << endl;
    cout << "\t\tlllllllll 4.    Exit                 lllllllllll" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t------------------------------------------------\n" << endl;
    cout << "Please select an option" << endl;
    cin >> option;
    system("cls"); 
}
```

PS: You can also create a function that prints the menu, get input from user and return the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you divide your code into chunks of cohesive functionality, you can put them into their own functions and the `main` function can be much simpler. Here's my recommendation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int getOption1()
{
   int option;

   cout << "\n\t\t------------------------------------------------" << endl;
   cout << "\t\tlllllllll           Menue            lllllllllll" << endl;
   cout << "\t\tlllllllll 1.    Array Basics         lllllllllll" << endl;
   cout << "\t\tlllllllll 2.    Searching Array      lllllllllll" << endl;
   cout << "\t\tlllllllll 3.    Sorting Array        lllllllllll" << endl;
   cout << "\t\tlllllllll 4.    Exit                 lllllllllll" << endl;
   cout << "\t\t------------------------------------------------\n" << endl;
   cout << "Please select an option" << endl;

   cin >> option;
   system("cls");

   return option;
}

char getOption2()
{
   char option;

   cout << "\nplease select an option\n" << endl;
   cout << "press m for main menue" << endl;
   cout << "press r for repeat" << endl;
   cout << "press e for exit" << endl;
   cin >> option;
   return option;
}

void doArrayBasics()
{
   int array[10];
   int sum = 0;
   float avg = 10;
   int mul = 1;

   int h = 1;
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {

      cout << h << "  Enter the Numbers  ";

      cin >> array[i];

      sum = sum + array[i];

      mul = mul*array[i];

      h++;
   }
   system("cls");

   for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
   {

      cout << "Given numbers" << j << " =  " << array[j] << "\n";


   }
   avg = sum / avg;
   int max = array[0];
   int min = array[0];


   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      if (array[i] > max)
      {
         max = array[i];
      }
      else if (array[i] < min)
      {
         min = array[i];
      }

   }
   cout << "\nSum of the Numbers= 4" << sum << endl;
   cout << "\nProduct of the Numbers is = " << mul << endl;
   cout << "\nThe Avg of Numbers is     = " << avg << endl;
   cout << "\nmaximum of the Numbers is = " << max << endl;
   cout << "\nminimum of the Numbers is = " << min << endl;
}

void doArraySearching()
{
   int array[10];
   int o;
   int index = -1;

   cout << "enter the elements of array" << endl;
   for (o = 0; o < 10; o++)
   {
      cin >> array[o];

   }
   system("cls");
   int p;
   cout << "enter value to find" << endl;
   cin >> p;
   for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
   {
      if (array[c] == p)
         index = c;
   }
   system("cls");
   if (index == -1)
   {
      cout << "no value found" << endl;
   }
   else
      cout << "Value found at\t" << index << endl;

}

void doArraySorting()
{
   system("cls");
   int a[10];
   int r;
   int t;
   int temp;

   cout << "Enter the array elements: " << endl;
   for (r = 0; r<10; ++r)
      cin >> a[r];
   system("cls");
   for (r = 0; r<10; ++r)
      for (t = 0; t<9; t++)
         if (a[r]<a[t])
         {
            temp = a[r];
            a[r] = a[t];
            a[t] = temp;
         }

   cout << "Array after sorting: " << endl;
   for (r = 0; r<10; r++)
      cout << a[r] << "\t ";

}

int main()
{
   int option1;
   char option2 = 'r';

   do
   {
      if ( option2 == 'r' )
      {
         option1 = getOption1();
      }

      switch (option1)
      {
         case 1:
            doArrayBasics();
            break;

         case 2:
            doArraySearching();
            break;

         case 3:
            doArraySorting();
            break;

         case 4:
            break;

         default:
            cout << "Invalid option " << option1 << endl;
      }

      if ( option1 != 4 )
      {
         option2 = getOption2();
      }

   } while (option1 != 4 && option2 != 'e' );

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inner loop to remove all gotos.

Remove `flip1:`, change `flip2:` to `do {`. The loop should begin like that:

```
do
{
    cout << "\n\t\t------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\t\tlllllllll           Menue            lllllllllll" << endl;
    cout << "\t\tlllllllll 1.    Array Basics         lllllllllll" << endl;
    cout << "\t\tlllllllll 2.    Searching Array      lllllllllll" << endl;
    cout << "\t\tlllllllll 3.    Sorting Array        lllllllllll" << endl;
    cout << "\t\tlllllllll 4.    Exit                 lllllllllll" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t------------------------------------------------\n" << endl;
    cout << "Please select an option" << endl;
    cin >> option;
    system("cls");
    do
    {
        if (option == 1)
        {
```

At the end of the loop, change:

```
if (q == 'm')
{
    system("cls");
    goto flip1;
}
if (q == 'r')
{
    system("cls");
    goto flip2;
}
if (q == 'e')
{
    return 0;
}
```

to :

```
    if (q == 'e')
    {
        return 0;
    }
    system("cls");
} while (q == 'r');
```

Breaking your code into functions will also make it more readable but is not mandatory to remove gotos.

Answer (score 0):

```
caveat: the following code not tested

int main()
{
    int array[10];
    int sum = 0;
    int desending;
    int mul = 1;

    float avg = 10;

    int option;
    int done = 0;
    int looping = 1;

    while( !done )
    {

        cout << "\n\t\t------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "\t\tlllllllll           Menue            lllllllllll" << endl;
        cout << "\t\tlllllllll 1.    Array Basics         lllllllllll" << endl;
        cout << "\t\tlllllllll 2.    Searching Array      lllllllllll" << endl;
        cout << "\t\tlllllllll 3.    Sorting Array        lllllllllll" << endl;
        cout << "\t\tlllllllll 4.    Exit                 lllllllllll" << endl;
        cout << "\t\t------------------------------------------------\n" << endl;
        cout << "Please select an option" << endl;
        cin >> option;
        system("cls");

        while( looping )
        {
            looping = 0;

            switch( option )
            {
                case 1:
                    int h = 1;
                    int i;
                    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {

                        cout << h << "  Enter the Numbers  ";

                        cin >> array[i];

                        sum = sum + array[i];

                        mul = mul*array[i];

                        h++;
                    }
                    system("cls");

                    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                    {

                        cout << "Given numbers" << j << " =  " << array[j] << "\n";


                    }
                    avg = sum / avg;
                    int max = array[0];
                    int min = array[0];


                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        if (array[i] > max)
                        {
                            max = array[i];
                        }
                        else if (array[i] < min)
                        {
                            min = array[i];
                        }

                    }
                    cout << "\nSum of the Numbers= 4" << sum << endl;
                    cout << "\nProduct of the Numbers is = " << mul << endl;
                    cout << "\nThe Avg of Numbers is     = " << avg << endl;
                    cout << "\nmaximum of the Numbers is = " << max << endl;
                    cout << "\nminimum of the Numbers is = " << min << endl;
                    break;

                case 2:        
                    int array[10], o, index = -1;
                    cout << "enter the elements of array" << endl;
                    for (o = 0; o < 10; o++)
                    {
                        cin >> array[o];

                    }

                    system("cls");
                    int p;
                    cout << "enter value to find" << endl;
                    cin >> p;

                    for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
                    {
                        if (array[c] == p)

                            index = c;
                    }

                    system("cls");
                    if (index == -1)
                    {
                        cout << "no value found" << endl;
                    }

                    else
                        cout << "Value found at\t" << index << endl;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    system("cls");
                    int a[10], r, t, temp;
                    cout << "Enter the array elements: " << endl;

                    for (r = 0; r<10; ++r)
                        cin >> a[r];

                    system("cls");

                    for (r = 0; r<10; ++r)
                    {
                        for (t = 0; t<9; t++)
                        {
                            if (a[r]<a[t])
                            {
                                temp = a[r];
                                a[r] = a[t];
                                a[t] = temp;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    cout << "Array after sorting: " << endl;

                    for (r = 0; r<10; r++)
                        cout << a[r] << "\t ";
                    break;

                case 4:
                    done = 1;
                    break;

                default:        
                    cout << "\nplease select an option\n" << endl;
                    cout << "press m for main menue" << endl;
                    cout << "press r for repeat" << endl;
                    cout << "press e for exit" << endl;
                    char q;

                    cin >> q;

                    switch( q )
                    {
                        case 'm':
                            system("cls");
                            // looping already set = 0
                            break;

                        case 'r':
                            system("cls");
                            looping = 1;
                            break;

                        case 'e':
                            done = 1;
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    } // end switch

                    break;
            } // end switch
        } // end while looping
    } // end while not done



    return 0;
} // end function: main
```